# Dynamic width for span

Tags: html, css

This is my code (please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6AHSp/)):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="left">Left text</span>
    <span id="middle">Very very very very very long middle text.</span>
    <span id="right">Right text</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

#middle {
    border: solid 1px green;
}

#right {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

I want the width of `#middle` to shrink as the window becomes smaller so that it doesn't clash with `#right`.

Comment: As long as it's a span, it's inline, so it won't wrap. Why is it not a DIV?

Comment: @ChristianWattengård: I'm happy to use a DIV, it you can get it to work! I'm also happy to use `inline-block`.

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-no-quirks-mode.htm

Comment: Is there any reason, why you don't use fixed width for #left and #right? If not, then it wont be any problem, right?

Comment: @Sn0opy: I could have #left fixed-width, but not #right. Could you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using any library like jQuery/Mootools etc.

Then, it'll be very easy, see here (using jQuery):

http://jsfiddle.net/6AHSp/15/

Answer (score 0):

I used sandeep's example for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VaDBX/

`overflow: hidden` only works, if you use `height`. It's a bit dirty, but works nicely w/o any JS.